# How to login with 3 parameters in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application where one username can belong to many companies. Thus to distinguish them, i need to use the both username and password as unique pair to login.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and i struggle to understand where the Login occurs.
Actually i can see where it validates the user but i don't find where it retrieves the user.

So where the

> Select user where username=xx and password=xx occurs ?

Asked differently : i did not find wher User is set ? I see User.Identity.Name it in the code, but i don't see :
User=Select....

Thanks
John

Comment: What if two users (john) from two different companies (A and B) both wanted to use the password ("thisisabadpassword")?

Comment: good question : currently i would not allow this.

Comment: Are you using the MVC template in VS2010?

Comment: What if user1 has pwd foo and another user1 has password foo1.  The second user1 mistypes his password as foo.  He is now logged into another user's account.  This is an unlikely but horrible scenario that could happen with shared usernames.  Consider another thing.  User forgets his pwd and wants an email sent.  How could you handle this?  I have just never heard of this scenario before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John, as you are using MVC. You wont be seeing any queries in the code aside from the LINQ syntax. Im guessing what you are trying to do is a many to many relationship between the User table and the Company table. (one user has multiple companys and 1 company has multiple users)
Pretty much database wise this would mean you need an extra table with both primairy keys of Company and Users.

To get back to your question. ASP.net MVC has its own membership provider. You can choose to either use the default one with its own tables or overwrite it and create ur own **custom membership provider** (with the ability to use ur own user table)

The default one pretty much should contain most of the basic attributes. (password reset, password salt, email,..)
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs
skip to the step: **Installing the Application Services** to generate the tables

However guessing you already have a database with your very own user table. you should overwrite the custom membership class.

Simply this would mean you make a new class that inherits from the abstract class "MembershipProvider"

```
public class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{ 

}
```

After that you have to let asp know that you will be overwriting the default membershipprovider with yours in **web.config**:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
             applicationName="MyApp"
             Description="My Membership Provider"
             passwordFormat="Clear"
             connectionStringName="MyMembershipConnection"
             type="MyApp.MyMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Some methods in the membership provider requires you to return or use an object of **MembershipUser**. Everything of how to implement this is right here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx
This is not a necessary step but its recommended.

Good luck john :)
If theres any confusion in the explanation, dont hesitate to ask

Comment: Thank you Anthony. You're right for the model part.So i have created a custom MemberShipser. Now i don't see where i get my USER ? I have overloaded the VerifyMethod but i don't see in which method i'll create the User ? If it is GetUser, where will it be called ?

Comment: You cant do anything with a membershipuser unless u have implemented a custom membershipprovider (a class that implements the methods of the interface MembershipProvider). Implement the methods that you need for your web application. (I suggest writing a seperate repository for your usertable and use it in the membership class. The reason I suggested creating a Membershipuser is because Membership.getUser() returns an object of that class. In short this means you read the current user from the database with the repository and you use the attributes to fill the membershipuser object

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

The code you're describing happens behind the scenes in the LogOn action of the Account Controller:

```
MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)
```

Which returns true for a valid user.  The user is then "signed in" with the next line in the code:

```
FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)
```

(You can see both of those functions defined in the AccountModels file under the Models folder)

If you want to also check company id while authenticating the user then you'll need to write your own auth method to replace ValidateUser.  Ths will depend on what you're using for your store (SQL?)

But, as a broader point, best practices you should not allow the same user name for different users.  It's just a bad idea and will lead to trouble.

UPDATE:

If I were recommending how to do this, I would suggest you user the UserProfile aspect of ASP.NET Membership.  It is designed to capture and store additional user variables (such as company) while still using the nicely built and secure Membership that they've written for you.  Read up on it, but below is my CreateUser function in the app I'm currently working on.  Note how I use the Profile to store first and last name as well as a flag that the user needs their password reset.

Again, this would preempt the ability to have multiple users with the same username, but I really think you ought to avoid that.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(string username, string email, string first, string last, string role)
{            
    string password;
    MembershipUser user;

    //Generate a random password
    password = Auth.CreateRandomPassword(6);

    try
    {
        //Create the user
        user = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email);

        //Add the user to the chosen role
        Roles.AddUserToRole(username, role);

        //Create the user profile
        UserProfile profile = UserProfile.GetUserProfile(username);

        profile.FirstName = first;
        profile.LastName = last;
        profile.ForcePasswordReset = true;

        profile.Save();

        EmailNewUser(username, email, password);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = ex.Message;
        HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    }

    return PartialView("UserTable", Auth.Users());

}
```

Comment: Depending on the version of Visual Studio and MVC you're using, it could be encapsulated differently or not at all.  The function being encapsulated is "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()" which is in the system.web.security library.

Comment: you're right it is SetAuthCookie. The name is so bad...But then where do i get/create my USER from my own DB

Comment: CreateUser is a method in the System.Web.Security.Membership object, but if you want to override that you'll have to write your own CreateUser function to store and load users from the database.  See my edited note above for my recommendation.